# J1939 data encoding

Tags: can, protocol

I have some trouble understanding the data encoding used in J1939; let's take temperature as an example: Section 5.1.5 of the protocol details the following:

| Parameter | Scaling (Resolution) | Limits(Range) | Parameter Offset Size |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Temperature | 1 deg C/bit | -40 to 210 deg C | -40 deg C |
| Temperature | 0.03125 deg C/bit | -273 to 1735 deg C | -273 deg C |

If we then consider SPN 171, Ambient air temp., the protocol says this:
[image: spn 171]

How do the bits translate to real world data, exactly?
Obviously it cant be just the sum of 0.03125 for each bit set to 1 of the 16 availble.

So the next thing i tried is (sorry i don't know how to format math formuale) the sums for i from 0 to 15 of (b*(2^i)*0.03125), where b is the i-th bit value; the offset value is then deducted from the result, to obtain the real value.
This approach more or less works, but it leaves me with a slight inconsistence of the data:
since 1735 + 273 = 2008, and the max of the sum detailed above amounts to (roughly) 2048, this results in about 40 unused values which would be above the specified Data Range.
I assume it could be used for diagnostic purposes, though I am note sure.

Am I approaching this correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You read the two bytes as an 16 bit unsigned integer, giving you a raw value from 0 to 65535.

You multiply this value with 0.03125 to get the temperature in degrees, then you subtract the offset of 273°C to get the actual temperature.

For example, say you get a value of 9376. Multiply that with 0.03125 giving you the value 293. Subtract the offset, and you have the actual temperature of 20°C.

Although, why they haven't utilized the entire available range of 0-65535 but only 0-64256, I have no idea. It seems as 0-64255 is a quite common valid data range for J1939 data.

Comment: Your formula is simpler, yet it has the same results; i suppose the wording of "resolution" expressed in degrees/bit might be misleading, surely it was for me...

Comment: Why would you subtract an offset of 273? This particular magic number should ring a bell, since 273 is the magic number of degrees between 0°K and 0°C (with Kelvin being the standardized SI unit). Aren't they just saying that they give the temperature in Kelvin? In that case you should _add_ 273 to get degrees Celsius.

Comment: The offsets are given as negative, and are added, which is of course arithmetically equivalent.  I believe they write it like this becaue it's thus in the very usual form of _y = mx + c_, where x is the raw value and y is the interpreted value and to normalise the arithmetic  across all the various parameters.  Most have an offset of 0 or negative, a few have positive offsets.  Some of the offsets are pretty arbitrary.

Comment: @Lundin: the standard explicitly says the unit for temperature measurement is the Celsius degree: for practical purposes like air/refrigerant/oil temp. in a vehicle it gives a more immediate feedback to both the end user and the engineers working on it; in the same way, i would consider practical/pragmatic to identify as minimum the absolute minimum known to man, as long as this does not introduce practical limitations on the maximum value... but that's just my 2 cents